# Query to check the average against a table and return a result if it is greater

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am writing a query where I take the average salary of one company and then check it against the the salaries of the other companies and if it is greater, return that company name as a result. What I have is the two separate parts. I have tried a derived table, a subquery, but I'm new to SQL and I can't figure out what I need to link them.

```
SELECT AVG(salary), company_name
FROM works
WHERE company_name = 'first_bank_corp';

SELECT salary,company_name
FROM works
WHERE salary > 'first_bank_corp';
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you just have to use a subquery ;)

```
  SELECT company_name,
         AVG(salary) AS avg_salary             
    FROM works
   WHERE avg_salary > (
             SELECT AVG(salary) 
               FROM works 
              WHERE company_name = 'first_bank_corp' 
         )
GROUP BY company_name
```

Comment: yes! you are the best! Sometimes I think a query needs to be super complicated to work…eh, guess thats why im new. thanks again! ill accept the answer when it lets me

Comment: also, is the top query getting its result from the sub. meaning, does the database run the sub part first, and then take that answer and apply it to the main query and then give the result?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Happy coding!

Edit: Yes. The subquery is run first and the value is returned to the main query.